# How to replace \n by space using sed command?

Tags: sed

I have  to collect a select query data to a CSV file. I want to use a `sed` command to replace `\n` from the data by a space.

I'm using this:

```
query | sed "s/\n/ /g" > file.csv .......
```

But it is not working. Only `\` is getting removed, while it should also remove `n`  and add a space. Please suggest something.

Comment: Does your query contain literally the string `\n`? Can you show example input and the expected output? If it really is `\n`, you have to escape the backslash: `sed 's/\\n/ /g'` or (double quotes require one more level of escaping) `sed "s/\\\n/ /g"`.

Comment: If the input is ...my\nname\nis\nrohinee.....then the output comes as ....mynnamenisnrohinee....and I want output as my name is rohinee....I have tried 's/\\n/  /g' and  s/\\\n/  /g'  also...still didn't got the output as expected

Comment: Can you [edit] the question with the example input and the output you get?

Comment: Just now showed that only

Comment: You should put that into the question, with proper code formatting. It's hard to tell what's going on in comments.

Comment: I suspect you store the input in a variable and then print it without quoting, thus having the shell remove the backslashes. Please show exactly how you're sending your input to sed.

Comment: Select comments from tablename | sed 's/\n/ /g' > file.csv

Comment: Yes ...I wasn't using the quotes to input ....that was the problem .... thanks allllloottt ....your answer helped ..

Comment: So you were NOT using `Select comments from tablename | sed 's/\n/ /g' > file.csv`, but storing your input in a variable? Please update the question ([edit]) to reflect that, or the answer to your problem is something that cannot be inferred from what's in the question right now.

Comment: How would `Select comments from tablename | sed 's/\n/ /g' > file.csv` even work? Where are you issuing that command?

Comment: What sed version are you using on what OS? No modern sed would remove a backslash given `sed "s/\n/ /g"` so I'm wondering if you're using a very old one on Solaris or something.

Comment: The query I was using was....mysql -uuserid -p -hhostname dbname -e "<query>" | sed "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g" > file.csv.      ........on a Linux server.... But this wasn't working to replace \n ......so  just to check another method of sed to replace \n .....I was using echo my\nname\nis | sed 's/\n/ /g' for testing purpose

Comment: @EdMorton I'm fairly sure the string containing `\n` was unescaped at some point and sed was a no-op, the backslashes removed by the shell.

Comment: Ah, yes, `echo my\nname\nis` on its own will already remove the backslashes because they're unquoted. Look at the output without sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n` is special to sed: it stands for the newline character. To replace a literal `\n`, you have to escape the backslash:

```
sed 's/\\n/ /g'
```

Notice that I've used [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes). If you use [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes), the backslash has a special meaning if followed by any of `$`, `` ` ``, `"`, `\`, or newline, i.e., `"\n"` is still `\n`, but `"\\n"` would become `\n`.

Since we want sed to see `\\n`, we'd have to use one of these:

- `sed "s/\\\n/ /g"` – the first `\\` becomes `\`, and `\n` doesn't change, resulting in `\\n`
- `sed "s/\\\\n/ /g"` – both pairs of `\\` are reduced to `\` and sed gets `\\n` as well

but single quotes are much simpler:

```
$ sed 's/\\n/ /g' <<< 'my\nname\nis\nrohinee'
my name is rohinee
```

---

From comments on the question, it became apparent that sed had nothing to do with removing the backslashes; the OP tried

```
echo my\nname\nis | sed 's/\n/ /g'
```

but the backslashes are removed by the shell:

```
$ echo my\nname\nis
mynnamenis
```

so even if the correct `\\n` were used, sed wouldn't find any matches. The correct way is

```
$ echo 'my\nname\nis' | sed 's/\\n/ /g'
my name is
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to replace newline with space, not necessarily using `sed`.

Use [tr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)):

```
tr '\n' ' '
```